# How to switch between views with BottomNavigationView?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragments, bottomnavigationview

I have an BottomNavigationView in my app and i want to change the views flawlessly.

I tried to start a new activity but it looks bad because the whole activty has an animation. Even if I disable the anim it still doesnt look great because the BottomNavigationView of the new activity overlaps the one from the old (the one before) so that the animation of the items gets interupted.

Material Design guidelines suggest to do it with views. The thing is I could mot find a way how to do. Every view should also have its own class and own fragments.

Is there a way to achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably switch between fragments instead of activities. See the developer references for more info. https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Example

This medium article gives more info on how you could do it: 
https://medium.com/@hitherejoe/exploring-the-android-design-support-library-bottom-navigation-drawer-548de699e8e0

So create your activity and add the BottomNavigationView to the bottom of it in the xml. Later use a switch case to show new fragments with the desired layout

Answer (score 0):

`Fragment`s is used with `BottomNavigationView` just like `viewPager`
you can replace fragments this way

```
BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView = (BottomNavigationView)
                findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation);
bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(
        new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {                 Fragment frag;
                switch (item.getItemId()) {
                    case R.id.action_favorites:
                        frag=new FavFragment();
                        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransactio().replace(R.id.container,frag);
                     break;
                    case R.id.action_another_frag:
                   //replace another fragment 
                    break;


                }
                return true;
            }
        });
```